# GPX files for iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, ios-simulator, gpx

Where I can find GPX files that I can import into my iOS Simulator?

The iOS Simulator only contains static locations around the world and walk / bike / car drive simulations.
This is not good enough for unit testing or other specific use cases.

This is the for GPX file: http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd

How can I simulate a movement along some custom route in Simulator or Xcode, cause it's needed in ios mobile development?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You create a route and generate a gpx file here - http://www.bikehike.co.uk/mapview.php

On another note it might help, are you aware the simulator can simulate movement if you run the simulator then select the following menu options:

- Debug
- Location
- You can select freeway drive, cycle ride, run etc

Comment: GPX files created from bikehike (and most other websites) are not compatible with Xcode. They use the <trk> tag whereas Xcode will only recognise <wpt> tags.  I've written an AWK script which converts common GPX files to Apple's format: https://gist.github.com/scotbond/8a61cf1f4a43973e570b

Comment: If you want to build the gps route in Google Maps but still get a compatible GPX file, this tool will help https://mapstogpx.com/mobiledev.php

Comment: The freeway drive, cycle ride, & run seem to be missing from Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: @AmitP I am not able the execute the awk script. Could you please help?  I tried this command: awk -F adjust_gpx_to_apple_format.awk bikehike_course >output.gpx

Comment: @Nil did you try ```chmod +x adjust*awk``` and run with ```./``` ?

Comment: @AmitP I am fairly beginner to the terminal commands. I did not understand "chmod +x adjust*awk and run with ./". Could you please elaborate. I don't see any script filename or output in this command.

Answer (score 36):

1. Run you app. In debug are you can find "Simulate location" button
   [image]

2.You can select one of default locations (here is list)

[image]

If you need a custom location

Create new file : File -> New ->File (Resources tab) GPX file
click (at the bottom of locations list) "Add GPX File to workspace"

3. Go to this [website](http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html) and get Latitude and Longitude of a Point that you need.
4. Edit GPX file that you have created.
5. Open "Simulate Location", the same as in step 1, and Your location from GPX file will be available in the list.The name of location will be same same as a name of the file.

Comment: Sorry - access forbidden to this site from point 1.

Comment: Hmm.. strange. Can't you open this site at all ? http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html

Comment: Creating the new file using XCode was enough to me =D tkx!

Comment: If you want to simulate many points or a whole route at a time then this tool will help http://hardkjarni.blogspot.fr/2015/11/testing-geo-location-in-ios-and-android_2.html

Answer (score 30):

Here is a simple GPX file with an entry for Ann Arbor, Michigan. You can just change the name and lat/lon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<gpx
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
version="1.1" 
creator="gpx-poi.com">

   <wpt lat="42.280826" lon="-83.743038">
      <name>Ann Arbor</name>
   </wpt>

</gpx>
```

Answer (score 16):

The following tool converts a Google Maps link (also works with Google Maps Directions) to a .gpx file.

https://mapstogpx.com/mobiledev.php

Simulating a trip duration is supported, custom durations may be specified. I enabled "Track Points" and Developer Settings > "Force Route as Waypoints" for a quick test, works flawlessly with Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: I'm the developer of this tool, you might be interested in my dev tool that is designed to produce gpx files that work with Xcode, Eclipse, Android Studio and Visual Studio https://mapstogpx.com/mobiledev.php

Comment: Thanks, I updated the link in my answer!

Comment: Extremely useful. Works for Xcode 8.2 as well.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to simulate a movement with gpx file you can use for example gpx file pasted below (works with Xcode 7). Just save it as route.gpx and add to your project.

```
<gpx>
<wpt lat="50.259290" lon="19.015630"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.260350" lon="19.015740"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.260450" lon="19.015780"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.260960" lon="19.014590"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.261600" lon="19.015260"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.262260" lon="19.015880"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.262780" lon="19.016470"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.263240" lon="19.016960"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.264240" lon="19.018150"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.264310" lon="19.018260"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.264460" lon="19.018400"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.265710" lon="19.019130"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.266030" lon="19.019290"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.266680" lon="19.019650"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.266960" lon="19.019830"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.268280" lon="19.020580"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.268420" lon="19.020580"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.268960" lon="19.020660"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.269820" lon="19.020810"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270670" lon="19.020900"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270760" lon="19.020930"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270820" lon="19.020980"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270940" lon="19.021150"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270980" lon="19.021250"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.271010" lon="19.021540"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270920" lon="19.022010"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270430" lon="19.024020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270300" lon="19.024700"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270070" lon="19.025680"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.269830" lon="19.026890"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.269290" lon="19.029270"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.269080" lon="19.030280"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.268720" lon="19.031810"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.268670" lon="19.032310"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.268710" lon="19.033300"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.268770" lon="19.034000"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.268850" lon="19.034350"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.269200" lon="19.035320"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.269360" lon="19.036020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.269510" lon="19.036870"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.269600" lon="19.037840"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270020" lon="19.040400"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270080" lon="19.040680"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270300" lon="19.041360"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.270710" lon="19.042790"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.271170" lon="19.044140"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.271720" lon="19.045680"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.271810" lon="19.046000"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.272480" lon="19.047770"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273030" lon="19.049390"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273760" lon="19.051370"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273800" lon="19.051520"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273920" lon="19.051800"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273870" lon="19.051890"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273860" lon="19.051980"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273900" lon="19.052120"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273940" lon="19.052180"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273980" lon="19.052200"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273980" lon="19.052240"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273950" lon="19.052630"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273820" lon="19.053190"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273790" lon="19.053450"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.273790" lon="19.053610"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.274080" lon="19.055820"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.275660" lon="19.061640"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.276120" lon="19.063620"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.276250" lon="19.064010"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.276590" lon="19.064850"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.276640" lon="19.065140"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.276950" lon="19.067700"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.277090" lon="19.068730"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.277110" lon="19.069600"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.277070" lon="19.069830"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.277260" lon="19.069940"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.277350" lon="19.069960"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.277490" lon="19.069960"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.277640" lon="19.069930"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.278350" lon="19.069690"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.278440" lon="19.069640"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.278600" lon="19.069670"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.278660" lon="19.069700"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.278670" lon="19.069740"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.278710" lon="19.069790"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.278710" lon="19.069850"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.278510" lon="19.072020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.278810" lon="19.072080"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.279170" lon="19.072120"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.279530" lon="19.072120"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.279730" lon="19.072020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.280180" lon="19.071610"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.280400" lon="19.071470"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.280580" lon="19.071380"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.281560" lon="19.070980"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.281940" lon="19.070890"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.282070" lon="19.070900"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.282250" lon="19.070950"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.282920" lon="19.071370"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.283160" lon="19.071500"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.283470" lon="19.071560"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.284460" lon="19.071630"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.284960" lon="19.071620"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.285380" lon="19.071560"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.286170" lon="19.071410"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.290610" lon="19.070510"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.290840" lon="19.070470"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.291010" lon="19.070470"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.291080" lon="19.070480"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.291170" lon="19.070520"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.291290" lon="19.070630"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.291420" lon="19.070880"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.291470" lon="19.071030"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.291510" lon="19.071480"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.291630" lon="19.073950"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.291950" lon="19.074000"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.293230" lon="19.074110"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.293440" lon="19.074150"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.293880" lon="19.074300"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.294560" lon="19.074430"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.295010" lon="19.074480"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.295250" lon="19.074480"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.295480" lon="19.074460"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.297190" lon="19.074210"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.297520" lon="19.074140"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.297770" lon="19.074040"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.299080" lon="19.073200"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.299580" lon="19.072840"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.300210" lon="19.072440"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.300480" lon="19.072330"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.300730" lon="19.072330"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.300900" lon="19.072370"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.301060" lon="19.072460"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.301180" lon="19.072560"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.301300" lon="19.072700"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.301980" lon="19.073670"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.302470" lon="19.074330"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.302630" lon="19.074500"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.302810" lon="19.074620"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.303460" lon="19.074900"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.304690" lon="19.075350"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.304990" lon="19.075420"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.305180" lon="19.075430"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.305440" lon="19.075420"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.305670" lon="19.075380"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.305950" lon="19.075320"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.306500" lon="19.075160"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.306820" lon="19.075010"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.306920" lon="19.074940"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.307030" lon="19.074820"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.307400" lon="19.074310"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.307610" lon="19.073890"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.307950" lon="19.072990"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.308130" lon="19.072580"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.309190" lon="19.070690"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.309390" lon="19.070400"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.309560" lon="19.070240"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.309680" lon="19.070170"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.309850" lon="19.070120"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.310660" lon="19.070030"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.311230" lon="19.069990"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.311540" lon="19.070010"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.312030" lon="19.070110"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.312870" lon="19.070460"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.313290" lon="19.070610"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.313390" lon="19.070600"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.313710" lon="19.070460"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.314310" lon="19.070230"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.314450" lon="19.070190"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.314650" lon="19.070180"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.314800" lon="19.070220"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.315190" lon="19.070410"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.315290" lon="19.070430"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.316050" lon="19.070490"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.316680" lon="19.070520"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.316810" lon="19.070570"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.317030" lon="19.070540"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.317080" lon="19.070570"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.317140" lon="19.070570"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.317170" lon="19.070590"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.317230" lon="19.070700"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.317010" lon="19.072570"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.316990" lon="19.072930"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.317000" lon="19.073290"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.317070" lon="19.073690"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.317150" lon="19.074010"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.317400" lon="19.074630"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.317990" lon="19.075920"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.318190" lon="19.076490"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.318290" lon="19.076840"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.318370" lon="19.077200"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.318510" lon="19.078150"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.318960" lon="19.081530"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.319070" lon="19.082160"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.319120" lon="19.082330"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.319220" lon="19.083130"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.319490" lon="19.084920"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.319490" lon="19.085140"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321120" lon="19.096470"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321150" lon="19.096540"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321450" lon="19.098600"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321670" lon="19.099820"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321840" lon="19.100660"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321830" lon="19.100770"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.322070" lon="19.102160"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.322110" lon="19.102500"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.322190" lon="19.102820"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.322600" lon="19.105090"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.322650" lon="19.105160"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.323010" lon="19.107150"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.322960" lon="19.107350"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.322900" lon="19.107460"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.322740" lon="19.107590"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.322530" lon="19.107710"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321660" lon="19.108050"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321570" lon="19.108070"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321460" lon="19.107930"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321420" lon="19.107760"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321470" lon="19.107560"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321540" lon="19.107480"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321580" lon="19.107470"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321650" lon="19.107420"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.321690" lon="19.107340"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.322520" lon="19.107030"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.323170" lon="19.106760"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.323600" lon="19.106610"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.324030" lon="19.106500"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.324290" lon="19.106450"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.324570" lon="19.106420"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.325010" lon="19.106420"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.325220" lon="19.106440"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.325540" lon="19.106500"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.325970" lon="19.106630"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.326890" lon="19.107030"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.332860" lon="19.109790"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.333430" lon="19.110010"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.334030" lon="19.110180"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.334360" lon="19.110240"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.334910" lon="19.110290"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.338470" lon="19.110270"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.339650" lon="19.110250"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.341840" lon="19.110270"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.348520" lon="19.110260"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.348870" lon="19.110290"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.349290" lon="19.110360"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.349670" lon="19.110470"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.350040" lon="19.110630"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.350340" lon="19.110790"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.350640" lon="19.110970"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.350910" lon="19.111170"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.351210" lon="19.111430"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.351560" lon="19.111810"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.351810" lon="19.112100"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.352050" lon="19.112420"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.352370" lon="19.112900"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.352510" lon="19.113150"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.354460" lon="19.116870"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.356110" lon="19.120080"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.357550" lon="19.122690"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.357790" lon="19.123160"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.359310" lon="19.125980"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.360040" lon="19.127260"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.360440" lon="19.127870"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.361990" lon="19.130040"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.363580" lon="19.132190"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.364230" lon="19.133100"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.365580" lon="19.134910"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.371260" lon="19.142660"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.371890" lon="19.143500"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.373590" lon="19.145670"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.374230" lon="19.146540"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.374700" lon="19.147260"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.374840" lon="19.147500"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.375400" lon="19.148550"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.375790" lon="19.149410"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.376070" lon="19.150120"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.376410" lon="19.151080"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.376530" lon="19.151480"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.376820" lon="19.152570"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.378610" lon="19.160470"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.378830" lon="19.161300"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.379140" lon="19.162210"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.382720" lon="19.170990"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.382930" lon="19.171540"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.383090" lon="19.172020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.383330" lon="19.172800"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.383620" lon="19.174010"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.384550" lon="19.178280"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.384710" lon="19.178910"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.384880" lon="19.179500"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.385080" lon="19.180080"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.385390" lon="19.180830"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.385580" lon="19.181220"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.385750" lon="19.181520"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.386090" lon="19.182010"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.386350" lon="19.182320"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.386790" lon="19.182740"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.387180" lon="19.183020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.387490" lon="19.183190"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.388800" lon="19.183820"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.389210" lon="19.184050"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.389410" lon="19.184180"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.395660" lon="19.188460"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.396270" lon="19.188860"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.397530" lon="19.189730"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.400300" lon="19.191600"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.400680" lon="19.191820"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.401830" lon="19.192400"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.402230" lon="19.192630"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.402620" lon="19.192890"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.402950" lon="19.193170"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.403600" lon="19.193860"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.403780" lon="19.194080"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.404170" lon="19.194620"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.405380" lon="19.196450"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.405610" lon="19.196830"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.405870" lon="19.197320"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.406810" lon="19.199230"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.407060" lon="19.199640"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.407240" lon="19.199890"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.407650" lon="19.200400"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.408370" lon="19.201040"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.409160" lon="19.201700"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.411040" lon="19.203240"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.412300" lon="19.204310"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.416260" lon="19.207580"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.416940" lon="19.208230"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.418300" lon="19.209340"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.419300" lon="19.210190"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.419780" lon="19.210630"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.420170" lon="19.210960"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.420280" lon="19.211000"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.422450" lon="19.212840"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.423520" lon="19.213660"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.423540" lon="19.213710"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.423920" lon="19.213930"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.424530" lon="19.214220"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.424780" lon="19.214320"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.425430" lon="19.214510"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.425770" lon="19.214560"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.427370" lon="19.214720"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.430000" lon="19.214860"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.432500" lon="19.215050"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.433120" lon="19.215090"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.434080" lon="19.215120"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.434750" lon="19.215180"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.435530" lon="19.215270"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.436060" lon="19.215390"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.436590" lon="19.215570"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.437040" lon="19.215790"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.437620" lon="19.216160"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.438230" lon="19.216660"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.438540" lon="19.216980"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.438840" lon="19.217250"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.439920" lon="19.218300"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.441520" lon="19.220000"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.443500" lon="19.222000"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.443810" lon="19.222330"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.444400" lon="19.222870"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.444650" lon="19.223060"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.445040" lon="19.223320"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.445480" lon="19.223560"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.446040" lon="19.223820"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.446900" lon="19.224190"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.447300" lon="19.224400"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.447560" lon="19.224580"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.449040" lon="19.225930"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.451090" lon="19.227870"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.451460" lon="19.228190"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.452220" lon="19.228780"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.453260" lon="19.229450"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.454200" lon="19.229870"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.456460" lon="19.230710"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.458160" lon="19.231380"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.458850" lon="19.231630"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.459310" lon="19.231750"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.460000" lon="19.231850"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.460540" lon="19.231800"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.460930" lon="19.231720"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.461230" lon="19.231620"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.462250" lon="19.231380"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.465020" lon="19.230640"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.466110" lon="19.230410"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.466460" lon="19.230310"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.466740" lon="19.230200"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.468610" lon="19.229740"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.469250" lon="19.229520"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.471110" lon="19.229020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.472860" lon="19.228580"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.473090" lon="19.228550"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.473640" lon="19.228530"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.474920" lon="19.228520"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.475350" lon="19.228480"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.475600" lon="19.228440"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.476330" lon="19.228230"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.476900" lon="19.227960"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.477460" lon="19.227620"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.477730" lon="19.227420"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.478460" lon="19.226810"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.478940" lon="19.226370"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.479390" lon="19.225930"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.480080" lon="19.225140"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.480840" lon="19.224060"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.484400" lon="19.218750"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.484740" lon="19.218310"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.484880" lon="19.218160"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.485350" lon="19.217730"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.486490" lon="19.216840"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.486800" lon="19.216570"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.487080" lon="19.216280"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.487340" lon="19.215980"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.487760" lon="19.215370"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.489930" lon="19.211730"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.491470" lon="19.209100"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.492580" lon="19.207260"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.492960" lon="19.206600"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.493260" lon="19.206130"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.493430" lon="19.205910"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.493780" lon="19.205520"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.493980" lon="19.205320"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.494350" lon="19.205020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.494970" lon="19.204590"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.498030" lon="19.202540"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.498870" lon="19.201960"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.499430" lon="19.201610"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.504790" lon="19.198010"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.505620" lon="19.197470"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.506110" lon="19.197200"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.506340" lon="19.197110"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.507360" lon="19.196810"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.509290" lon="19.196290"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.510120" lon="19.196050"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.510920" lon="19.195870"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.516580" lon="19.194290"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.517830" lon="19.194020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.519680" lon="19.193660"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.523150" lon="19.192940"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.526090" lon="19.192380"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.526650" lon="19.192230"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.529710" lon="19.191270"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.532230" lon="19.190450"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.532760" lon="19.190220"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.533580" lon="19.189800"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.535510" lon="19.188670"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.535920" lon="19.188410"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.536370" lon="19.188040"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.536700" lon="19.187720"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.537120" lon="19.187180"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.537270" lon="19.186960"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.537470" lon="19.186610"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.537790" lon="19.186020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.539180" lon="19.183270"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.539520" lon="19.182700"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.539960" lon="19.182160"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.539990" lon="19.182150"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.540350" lon="19.181770"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.540830" lon="19.181370"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.541050" lon="19.181210"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.541280" lon="19.181070"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.541480" lon="19.180970"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.541970" lon="19.180820"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.542380" lon="19.180760"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.545520" lon="19.180760"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.546190" lon="19.180740"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.546550" lon="19.180710"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.546720" lon="19.180680"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.547160" lon="19.180560"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.549400" lon="19.179670"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.550200" lon="19.179320"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.550870" lon="19.179060"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.552690" lon="19.178290"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.553880" lon="19.177810"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.555350" lon="19.177310"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.556120" lon="19.177020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.561140" lon="19.175240"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.561540" lon="19.175070"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.561990" lon="19.174790"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.562790" lon="19.174170"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.565330" lon="19.171350"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.568590" lon="19.167550"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.569360" lon="19.166730"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.569790" lon="19.166390"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.571030" lon="19.165620"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.573660" lon="19.164080"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.575170" lon="19.163160"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.575450" lon="19.163020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.575850" lon="19.162860"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.576230" lon="19.162780"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.576620" lon="19.162750"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.577110" lon="19.162800"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.579170" lon="19.163250"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.581640" lon="19.163840"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.582320" lon="19.163960"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.583100" lon="19.164010"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.583790" lon="19.163860"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.584370" lon="19.163650"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.585550" lon="19.163130"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.586930" lon="19.162550"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.587600" lon="19.162200"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.588070" lon="19.161870"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.588790" lon="19.161260"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.589230" lon="19.160790"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.589570" lon="19.160370"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.590200" lon="19.159450"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.590540" lon="19.158850"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.593140" lon="19.153130"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.593470" lon="19.152480"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.593700" lon="19.152120"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.593960" lon="19.151740"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.594240" lon="19.151380"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.594500" lon="19.151080"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.594770" lon="19.150810"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.595340" lon="19.150360"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.595950" lon="19.149980"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.596290" lon="19.149820"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.596820" lon="19.149660"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.597040" lon="19.149600"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.597570" lon="19.149530"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.598120" lon="19.149580"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.598540" lon="19.149650"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.598780" lon="19.149710"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.599170" lon="19.149850"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.599500" lon="19.150000"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.599810" lon="19.150150"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.600140" lon="19.150350"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.600450" lon="19.150590"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.605290" lon="19.154000"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.605500" lon="19.154140"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.606020" lon="19.154420"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.606440" lon="19.154590"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.606850" lon="19.154690"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.607310" lon="19.154720"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.607610" lon="19.154720"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.608630" lon="19.154600"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.609200" lon="19.154420"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.609820" lon="19.154140"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.612860" lon="19.152650"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.613600" lon="19.152230"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.614080" lon="19.151910"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.620120" lon="19.147220"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.620830" lon="19.146640"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.622740" lon="19.145170"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.623850" lon="19.144290"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.628890" lon="19.140070"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.629500" lon="19.139640"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.630510" lon="19.138830"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.632320" lon="19.137150"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.632810" lon="19.136740"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.633310" lon="19.136410"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.633850" lon="19.136140"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.634160" lon="19.136020"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.634380" lon="19.135960"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.634790" lon="19.135890"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.635660" lon="19.135830"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.638180" lon="19.135750"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.640590" lon="19.135780"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.641040" lon="19.135750"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.641800" lon="19.135650"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.642390" lon="19.135510"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.650830" lon="19.132950"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.652190" lon="19.132520"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.653640" lon="19.132030"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.657670" lon="19.130760"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.658350" lon="19.130560"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.658900" lon="19.130370"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.659570" lon="19.130100"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.659870" lon="19.129960"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.660500" lon="19.129610"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.660820" lon="19.129360"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.661130" lon="19.129060"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.661430" lon="19.128750"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.661930" lon="19.128080"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.662910" lon="19.126680"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.663630" lon="19.125720"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.663940" lon="19.125360"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.664870" lon="19.124440"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.665340" lon="19.124040"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.666040" lon="19.123560"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.666650" lon="19.123210"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.666960" lon="19.123070"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.667630" lon="19.122850"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.668650" lon="19.122630"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.669450" lon="19.122550"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.670480" lon="19.122620"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.670680" lon="19.122620"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.671280" lon="19.122780"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.671940" lon="19.123000"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.672600" lon="19.123300"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.673290" lon="19.123690"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.675950" lon="19.125410"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.676870" lon="19.126040"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.677700" lon="19.126560"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.680760" lon="19.128570"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.682680" lon="19.129810"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.685790" lon="19.131860"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.688510" lon="19.133700"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.691170" lon="19.135450"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.692490" lon="19.136250"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.695320" lon="19.138090"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.698200" lon="19.140040"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.698720" lon="19.140360"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.699380" lon="19.140830"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.702790" lon="19.142990"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.705080" lon="19.144510"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.709170" lon="19.147140"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.711930" lon="19.148990"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.715420" lon="19.151940"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.716990" lon="19.153230"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.717970" lon="19.154070"></wpt>
<wpt lat="50.721960" lon="19.157410"></wpt>
</gpx>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go to https://github.com/doronkatz/GFXLocations which is a github repository of some cities (for Australia). You can generate new ones and contribute back to that.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal and fastest solution (with accuracy), is to:

1. Create a Path via Google Earth
2. Save the path to an .kml file (on your desktop)
3. Open the .kml and copy all the geolocation points (notably the long, lat, elvations)
4. Paste it in TextMate or similar
5. Use this RegEx Find & Replace: 
   Find: `(.*?),(.*?),0`  (there is a space at the end of this regex)
   Replace: `<wpt lat="$2" lon="$1" />`
6. Add  to the begining and  to the end, and save it as a .gpx
7. Use that gpx file in Xcode after running the App in debug: "Simulate Location" add the GPX, then select it again to start the simulation of the path you made.

Answer (score -7):

Create yourself one:

Write a program that gets input:

1. startLocation (lat,lon)
2. endLocation,
3. speed

Determine distance between start and end in meters.
Then do a linear interpolation between start and end, with calculated step.
Step is derived from distance and speed

Then create the gpx file with simple text output.

Comment: That's way too simple.