# Send GPS location to iOS device via bluetooch

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, gps

We are looking for a way to send GPS location to iPhone or iPad through bluetooth. The benefits of doing so is that an external GPS device could produce more accurate location than the build-in GPS device in iOS. For our testing purposes, it would also be nice to be able to produce GPS manually by QAs.

We are pretty sure this is possible but we don't know how. We heard about this kind of external GPS device from one of our customers. Simple googling we found this one [this device](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/2953/files/BE-GPS-2200-User-Guide-r1.2.pdf?760), which does exactly what we are looking for.

We know that it is possible to generate fake GPS location using GPX file through Xcode. Please refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908356/how-to-set-fake-gps-location-on-ios-real-device) for more details. But this is not what we are looking for. We don't want to teach the QA how to build and debug with Xcode.

**In a nutshell, we want to know how to send GPS location to iOS device via bluetooth. Eventually, we would like to build a simple app (maybe on Mac) and we can set up some GPS locations for testing.**

P.S.: A similar [question](http://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1778857-Using-iPhone-as-a-Bluetooth-GPS-receiver) was asked a couple of years ago but it seems very much outdated. This [link](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204387) explains the supported supported bluetooth profiles by Apple. But I don't see anything related.

Any link to sample code or documentation will be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as we know, we are not able to send GPS location to our device via Bluetooth. Apple only allow pairing with a small set of known Bluetooth GPS manufactures.