# Change user location in GMSMapView

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to set a custom user location in GMSMapView. The locations is based on iBeacons. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change user location.

There are two options though:

1. Use a custom marker (annotation) that acts as a user location.
2. You can implement GPS Spoofing where you can simulate the user current location. See this [How to set fake GPS location on IOS real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908356/how-to-set-fake-gps-location-on-ios-real-device][1])