# set user location on map by coding

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, cllocationcoordinate2d

Is there a way to set the `mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate` by code?

I know there is  `CLLocationCoordinate2D` for set coordinates but then it isn't the userLocationCoordinate.

I have tried to assign a number to `mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude`, but then I get "this expression is not assignable"

```
mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude = 0;
```

So is there a way to set UserLocation (except from setting a default location in the simulator)?

Answer (score 0):

It may not possible to set `MKUserLocation` coz in its definition it suggest that it is `readonly` Property.

```
 // The annotation representing the user's location
 @property (nonatomic, readonly) MKUserLocation *userLocation;
```

Instead of this, you can add `MKAnnotationView` in

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

where you want to highlight, as User location like,

May It help you.

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

you can not set user's current location through code as it's read-only property.

You can use CLLocationManager if you want user's current location.
please refer below link for that
[Link 1](http://datacalculation.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-fix-cllocationmanager-location.html)
[Link 2](http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/)

Or you can use gpx file to set your device's current location whatever you want.
To do that please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292783/where-to-find-gpx-file-for-ios-simulator)

Hope this will help you.