# How to simulate location change on Xcode 7.3?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to simulate location change on Xcode 7.3. I only know how to enable static GPS simulation (by choosing one of city from Debug->Simulate Location). Is there any other option to simulate e.g car ride?

Answer (score 0):

On this page: [Where to find GPX file for iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292783/where-to-find-gpx-file-for-ios-simulator) 'woot586', who currently has the 'correct answer' indicates that you can do so and gives a hint of how to make it happen.

Another way, as indicated by 'Leszek S' on the same page above, you can simulate movement by creating a route.gpx file with a series of barely changing latitudes/longitudes.